# How to read JSON object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I have a JSON object like

```
{"status":"200","id":"23","username":"nipinponmudi@gmail.com","fname":"hh","laname":"hh","timezone":"2","createdate":"2011-09-20 22:05:24","key":"db3f57a8f2b9abd9d51916232f5a77b9"}
```

The object above is a response from a server.I want to display these objects in corresponding textfields on the viewdidload method.I want to read this object and display separately in textfields.I need to extract the username,fname,lname only.No need to read the status

Comment: not iphone related, but json in general. you could parse it yourself, or look for a bunch of json parser out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at https://github.com/stig/json-framework/ . I'm sure they are so many source and example out there to show you.

```
NSString *jsonString = @{"status":"200","id":"23","username":"nipinponmudi@gmail.com","fname":"hh","laname":"hh","timezone":"2","createdate":"2011-09-20 22:05:24","key":"db3f57a8f2b9abd9d51916232f5a77b9"}";
SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new];
id object = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];

txtName.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
```